# Set focus on popup panel and dynamically rendered fields in RichFaces 4.1.0

Tags: richfaces

I have a JSF page in which certain fields are rendered dynamically when "onchange" event of other field is called. Also there is a popup panel which opens on click of a button.
Here is the simplified version of the page:

```
<h:form id="testForm">
        <h:panelGrid id="testPanel" columns="2">
            <h:inputText id="text0" />
            <h:inputText id="text1">
                <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{popupMBean.renderDynamicData}"
                    render="@form" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:inputText id="text2" rendered="#{popupMBean.renderDynamic}" />
            <h:inputText id="text3" />
            <a4j:commandButton id="open" value="Open" render="testPopup"
                oncomplete="#{rich:component('testPopup')}.show();" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

    <rich:popupPanel id="testPopup" height="100"
        domElementAttachment="form" header="Test">
        <f:facet name="controls">
            <h:commandButton value="Close"
                onclick="#{rich:component('testPopup')}.hide()"></h:commandButton>
        </f:facet>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="test">
            <a4j:commandButton id="first" value="First" />
            <a4j:commandButton id="second" value="Second" />
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </rich:popupPanel>
```

I have a requirement that I need to traverse through all the fields using keyboard. Following are the problems faced:

1. When I click the 'Open' button it shows the popup panel but the
   focus is not set to the first input element in the popup.
2. When the user closes the popup then the focus should be set to either the field which generated the popup or to the field next to it.
3. After the change event on field "text1" is called, the focus shifts back to the first input element on page i.e. "text0" instead of the newly rendered field "text2".

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through various forums, I found that this issue is related to the bug in Rich Faces 4.1 (RF- 10758).

This bug has been resolved by the Jboss community in in RichFaces 4.2.3 release by making changes in popupPanel.js file. In **popupPanel.js** there is a **processAllFocusElements** function which compares between "root" (parent window) and "this.div" (child window). While "root" is a simple DOM element, "this.div" is a jQuery collection of elements and thus a comparison between both always fails. Therefore, (root != this.div.get(0) ) should be written instead of (root != this.div).

But I cannot migrate to RichFaces 4.2 as of now. So I decided to override the default function **processAllFocusElements** with the following code:

```
jQuery.extend(RichFaces.ui.PopupPanel.prototype, {
        processAllFocusElements: function(root, callback) {
            var idx = -1;
            var tagName;
            var formElements = "|a|input|select|button|textarea|";
            if (root.focus &amp;&amp; root.nodeType == 1 &amp;&amp; (tagName = root.tagName) &amp;&amp;
                // Many not visible elements have focus method, we is had to avoid processing them.
                (idx = formElements.indexOf(tagName.toLowerCase())) != -1 &amp;&amp;
                formElements.charAt(idx - 1) === '|' &amp;&amp;
                formElements.charAt(idx + tagName.length) === '|' &amp;&amp;
                !root.disabled &amp;&amp; root.type != "hidden") {
                callback.call(this, root);
            } else {
                if (root != this.div.get(0)) {
                    var child = root.firstChild;
                    while (child) {
                        if (!child.style || child.style.display != 'none') {
                            this.processAllFocusElements(child, callback);
                        }
                        child = child.nextSibling;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
    )
```

This has solved my problem (1) in original question but other issues still remain to be handled.